# Easy Pie Chart - percentage not centered

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, progress-bar

I'm using Easy Pie Chart: https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart

and everything works nice except for the percentage that doesn't show up in the middle of the circle, but in the bottom-left corner (outside the circle).

I've searched for a solution and I found this: [Easy Pie Chart : Bug percentage not centered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274928/easy-pie-chart-bug-percentage-not-centered) but it didn't solve the issue (the class"chart" was already precent in my case).

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="chart" data-percent="73">73%</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('.chart').easyPieChart({      
    animate: 2000,
    scaleColor: false,
    lineWidth: 12,
    lineCap: 'square',
    size: 100,
    trackColor: '#e5e5e5',
    barColor: '#3da0ea'
});
});
```

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution to this question through the support board. It depends on if you're using jquery or angular for it. In your case with jquery you need to access the event and then update the node's contents. https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart/issues/88